# TypeError: (0 , _native.createNavigatorFactory) is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, ui-testing, react-test-renderer

Trying to perform `npm test` on my React Native application, unit testing with Jest are working fine. However with `react-test-renderer` it complaining the following issue.

```
FAIL  __tests__/App-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: (0 , _native.createNavigatorFactory) is not a function

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/material-top- tabs/lib/commonjs/navigators/createMaterialTopTabNavigator.tsx:50:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/material-top-tabs/lib/commonjs/index.tsx:4:1)
```

I did not write this test case, it comes default while the project was created. I'm expecting to see a pass unit test from here, what seems to be the issue from the `react-test-renderer`?

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have to mock `renderer`

I have had the similar issue with `useHeaderHeight`

example I had `import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/stack';`
in my screen file. So when I was running the test I was getting the same error

```
 FAIL  src/screens/expressCheckout/ExpressCheckoutScreen.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: (0 , _native.createNavigatorFactory) is not a function

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/navigators/createStackNavigator.tsx:96:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/index.tsx:9:1)
```

Which I fixed by adding below mentioned jest mock in my test file and then I was able to run my tests

```
jest.mock('@react-navigation/stack', () => ({
  useHeaderHeight: (): number => 0,
}));
```